# Как завести сокеты на django на сервере nginx (gunicorn+uvicorn)?

Tags: python, django, redis, channels

Сам сайт работает, все загружается, кроме сокетов

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.56.103:8080/ws' failed:
```

nginx:

```
upstream channels-backend {
  server localhost:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 192.168.56.103;

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  location /static/ {
    root /home/yasf/testdjango5;
  }

  location /media/ {
    root /home/yasf/testdjango5;
  }

  location /admin/static/ {
    root /home/yasf/testdjango5;
  }

  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
  }
  
  location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

Все это лежит на VirtualBox, пытаюсь просто разобраться с django, и вот одна из вещей это сокеты.
Также не мало важно то, что если запускать через python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000, через asgi естественно, то все прекрасно отрабатывает

script.js (то, где и применяются сокеты):

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.56.103:8000/ws');

socket.onopen = function (e) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Hello from Js client'
    }));
};

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    try {
        console.log(event);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error:', e.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: Во-первых, `http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:8080` — тут явно чушь написана. Во-вторых, где у вас websocket-сервер находится-то? Не на gunicorn же наверное?

Comment: Без понятия что за websocket-сервер, и не знаю как его запускать даже. Просто через библиотеку channels на django создал Consumer, где и лежит сокет и все

Comment: Проблему решил. Просто нужно было отдельно через daphne запустить asgi сервер для сокетов.
Более подробно тут -> https://github.com/mitchtabian/HOWTO-django-channels-daphne?tab=readme-ov-file#deploying-django-channels-with-daphne--systemd. Заголовок "Deploying Django Channels with Daphne & Systemd"